# Is there a devenv flag to disable pdb generation at compile time?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, pdb-files

Our continuous integration system currently runs a perl script to parse our sln/proj files to set the following options:

DebugInformationFormat="0" 
GenerateDebugInformation="FALSE"

Preventing generation of pdbs allows us to increase the parallelization of the CIS compile. However, this method seems hacky and occasionally fails - is there a better method?

The only alternative I can think of is adding a configuration called RELEASE_NOPDB, but I'm afraid that will complicate maintenance of the RELEASE configuration - maintainers will have to ensure to reflect all changes to the NOPDB version when changes are made.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111631/visual-studio-solutions-multiple-project-how-to-effectively-propagate-project-p#111648) mentions *.vsprops files as a way to propagate "global" information across projects. Perhaps they can solve your problem too.

Otherwise, [I would suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111631/visual-studio-solutions-multiple-project-how-to-effectively-propagate-project-p#111657) that you let [CMake](http://www.cmake.org) generate your solution and project files.